# The right way to remove a class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, frontend

I have a simple question that interests me a lot:
If I want to remove a CSS class with jQuery, what's the right way?
1. removing after checking for the existence of the class?

```
if($(div).hasClass('css-class')) {
  $(div).removeClass('css-class');
}
```

2. just removing it?

```
$(div).removeClass('css-class');
```

3.any other suggestions?

Comment: You can just remove it, using method num. 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove it. It's not like jQuery's going to throw an error (or anything like that) if the element does not have the class you're removing.

```
$(div).removeClass('css-class');
```

Comment: Thanks! what about adding a class? the check is necessary?
Will it be added twice if I don't check?

Comment: +1 to @Matt Ball. Errors are thrown when trying to delete or remove a non-existent element , not when classes are being removed.

Comment: @harsha not with jQuery. If you try to select and then remove a non-existent element, it will silently do nothing.

Comment: Right,sorry, I was thinking of vanilla JS .. I mean an error in the error console .

Answer (score 0):

For removing class using jquery I prefer the 1st option for checking existence of class for a specific dom element and then remove the class applied for that DOM element eventhough jquery does not throw any error even if that DOM element has not been applied that class

E.g.

```
 if($(div).hasClass('css-class')) {
   $(div).removeClass('css-class');
 }
```

Comment: redundant check will add more ops.